Can a weakly locally compact US space not be locally relatively compact?
In $\pi$-base, the property Weakly locally compact is defined as every point having a compact neighborhood, and Locally relatively compact is defined as every point having a closed and compact neighborhood. Clearly, if every compact is closed in the space (this is what we usually called KC), then weak local compactness implies local relative compactness. But what if the space is only US, meaning that every sequence has at most one limit? There are currectly no counterexamples in $\pi$-base. Thank you in advance.

One might even wonder about the stronger property of Weak Hausdorff: https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P143

I might misunderstand your comment, but Weak Hausdorff does imply US: https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Weak+Hausdorff%2B%7EUS

@StevenClontz Yes of course, sorry my bad!
